# Profile LLVM passes through Clang

Tags: compilation, clang, llvm

I want to profile LLVM passes i.e. I would like to know how much time is spent in each pass. I see that llc has an option --time-passes to emit report but how do I pass it via Clang?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably looking for `-ftime-report`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Why this doesn't come up when I do clang++ --help? Is it guarded under some #defs?

Comment: @username_4567: Good question - I don't know. Actually a lot of clang switches aren't documented. Taking a look at GCC's documentation often helps...